# Compile error for Linux kernel 4.10.8 targeting ARM

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, cross-compiling, kbuild

I'm trying to cross compile the Linux kernel 4.10.8 for arm, but get this error:

```
      CC [M]  drivers/vhost/vhost.o
In file included from ./include/uapi/linux/stddef.h:1:0,
                 from ./include/linux/stddef.h:4,
                 from ./include/uapi/linux/posix_types.h:4,
                 from ./include/uapi/linux/types.h:13,
                 from ./include/linux/types.h:5,
                 from ./include/uapi/asm-generic/fcntl.h:4,
                 from ./arch/arm/include/uapi/asm/fcntl.h:9,
                 from ./include/uapi/linux/fcntl.h:4,
                 from ./include/linux/fcntl.h:4,
                 from ./include/linux/eventfd.h:11,
                 from drivers/vhost/vhost.c:14:
drivers/vhost/vhost.c: In function ‘vhost_vring_ioctl’:
./include/linux/compiler.h:518:38: error: call to ‘__compiletime_assert_1357’ declared with attribute error: BUILD_BUG_ON failed: __alignof__ *vq->avail > VRING_AVAIL_ALIGN_SIZE
  _compiletime_assert(condition, msg, __compiletime_assert_, __LINE__)enter
```

Any idea how to solve this?
I dont know what this module is used for, so I dont know if I actually need to compile it, but I cant find where in menuconfig to disable this module?

Comment: Instructions on how to build is done with a [`Makefile`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/vhost/Makefile).  You can see the symbol is **CONFIG_VHOST** and it will be found (usually) in a [`Kconfig`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/vhost/Kconfig) in the same directory.  You can use '?' in `make menuconfig` to find the location of the symbol.  You have one of **VHOST_NET**, **VHOST_SCSI** or **VHOST_VSOCK** defined.  It maybe selected by yet some other features.  '?' will give this info as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This module (CONFIG_VHOST) usually requires when you need `virtualization` support. If you don't require it disable it in the `make menuconfig`.

If you don't need virtualization, you can ignore it and proceed your build.